# file not found when clicking a problem in vscode for an angular project

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I started using Visual Studio code for my angular 15 project.

I have a problem that when the editor detects errors and i can see them on the Problems Tab:

[image: Problems tab]

and I double click on one of the problems to open the relevant file, it gives me the error `The editor could not be opened because the file was not found`

[image: File not found Error]

as you can see in the problem, the Error talks about `src/app/yt-player/yt-player.component.ts`

and the file does exists

[image: Actual File]

I googled and it's related to something related to relative path maybe ?

`.vscode` directory is in the root of the project and the location relative to the root of the project is correct.

what am I missing ?

these are the list of my installed extensions:

```
Angular.ng-template
bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client
cschlosser.doxdocgen
ecmel.vscode-html-css
EditorConfig.EditorConfig
eg2.vscode-npm-script
golang.go
jeff-hykin.better-cpp-syntax
johnpapa.Angular2
ms-azuretools.vscode-docker
ms-ossdata.vscode-postgresql
ms-python.isort
ms-python.python
ms-python.vscode-pylance
ms-toolsai.jupyter
ms-toolsai.jupyter-keymap
ms-toolsai.jupyter-renderers
ms-toolsai.vscode-jupyter-cell-tags
ms-toolsai.vscode-jupyter-slideshow
ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers
ms-vscode.cmake-tools
ms-vscode.cpptools
ms-vscode.cpptools-extension-pack
ms-vscode.cpptools-themes
mtxr.sqltools
nrwl.angular-console
PKief.material-icon-theme
twxs.cmake
zhuangtongfa.material-theme
```

## update - this is confusing

[image: another error example]

as you can see here i have 3 errors, the bottom one and the top one are on the same file, `src/app/yt-player/yt-player.component.html` with the same  error, the bottom error states from which component it's derived from, the top error doesn't.

when I click on the bottom error it jumps to the file properly, at the top error it gives me file not found.

Comment: [1] Can you share a list of your extensions? You can run the command `code --list-extensions > extensions.txt` to save them into a file. I would recommend that you disable all your linting-related extensions, restart VSCode and enable them again.
[2] Do you have ESLint installed? That may be the culprit.

Comment: @aghwotu - added the extensions list, i don't see any lint related extensions and i don't have lint packages in my angular project

Comment: @aghwotu - well.. i removed the .vscode directory, started the project, close it, added the same .vscode directory again and now things work! yay! any ideas why? if you do please type it as an answer. thanks

Comment: Hey @ufk glad it's all working now. I think restarting it did the trick here.

Comment: @aghwotu - unfortunately it's keep happening again and again in my other angular projects and restarting doesn't help, tried to use vscode-insiders maybe it's a bug that was fixed but results are the same.